# Sharing files between the same app on different devices - Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a windows store app project, is it possible to send files to another user on a different device using my app, i would have my app open , send a file someway and the other user would get it on his device also with the app installed.

Comment: I would need more information to help you. Will both your users use the application at the same location therefor having access to a directory to write/read on a local server ?(in a business for example where users go to a building at the start of the day). If not is it an application for anybody to use across the world/country ?

Comment: they would be near each other yes, for example im standing near a partner and i would send him a pdf file and he would get it on his app

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything built-in to my knowledge, but you can use something like NFC, GPS, Bluetooth or a web service with user relationships to establish the link and then to send it - use something like WI-FI, Ethernet, a web service - your own or something like OneDrive, DropBox, Google Drive etc...